# Can't access Session Cache from Invocable Method

Tags: invocable-method, cache, bots, einstein-bots, sessionstorage

I have a use case where a user fills out a form on one page, navigates to a second page, then starts an Einstein Bot flow, which I would like to have access to the values the user entered on the first page.

Initially I planned to put the values in the URL, however this is not an ideal solution due to maximum URL lengths. I was hoping to use the Session Cache to do this, however when calling it in an invocable method from the Bot Flow:

```
Cache.Session.put('userCaseChatValues', caseValues);
//majority of below method omitted for brevity
@InvocableMethod(label='Get BOT URL Params' )
public static List<UrlParameters> getUrlParameters (List<String> routableId) {
        String caseValues = (String)Cache.Session.get('userCaseChatValues');
        CaseData data = (CaseData)JSON.deserialize(caseValues, CaseData.class);
        System.debug('got from storage ' + data);
}
```

I received this error:

```
[{"actionName":"CSIR_CCA_CaseIntakeHelper",
 "errors":[{"statusCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION",
            "message":"An Apex error occurred:
            cache.Session.SessionCacheNoSessionException: 
            Failed Cache.Session.getDefault():Session not found -
           Session Cache not supported",
  "fields":[]}],"isSuccess":false,"outputValues":null}]
```

I know the Session Cache is not available when using Asynchronous Apex, but is it not possible to call it from an Invocable method either?

Is there another way I could access the Session Cache from an Einstein bot flow?

Comment: Session Cache "allowed" context is vague, e.g. here's another [issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGtnQAG). If you really want cache, a better solution is to use  Org-wide cache: manufacture a unique key that's good enough to represent your bot flow "session".